# Jquery on event no binding after FB login sdk call

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a SPA that has a FB login button that shows when the user is not logged in. If the user is logged in than a different page shows.

For some reason, when my fb login determines that the user is NOT logged in, it goes and gets the html from the correct div (by way of ID) and places the html into the stage div... BUT, then my event listener on that FBLogin button doesn't work/exist, is not bound?!

```
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                // FB JavaScript SDK configuration and setup
                FB.init({
                  appId      : 'SOME ID', // FB App ID
                  cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                  xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                  version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
                });

                // Check whether the user already logged in
                FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                    if (response.status === 'connected') {
                        //display user data
                        getFbUserData();
                        changeToPage("appFeed");
                    } else {
                        changeToPage("loginprompt");
                    }
                });
            };

            // Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

            // Facebook login with JavaScript SDK
            function fbLogin() {
                FB.login(function (response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        // Get and display the user profile data
                        getFbUserData();
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.';
                    }
                }, {scope: 'email'});
            }

            // Fetch the user profile data from facebook
            function getFbUserData(){
                FB.api('/me', {locale: 'en_US', fields: 'id,first_name,last_name,email,link,gender,locale,picture'},
                function (response) {
                    // Save user data
                    console.log(response.first_name);
                });
            }


            function changeToPage(loadPage)
            {
                // html is contained within another div so get the html and place it into our stage div. 
                var loadPageHTML = $("#"+loadPage).html();

                // move it into the page... 
                $(".stage").html(loadPageHTML);
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".fbReg").on("click", function()
                {
                    alert("clicked");
                });
            });
```

The html basics I'm using is...

```
    <div id="application"> 

        <!-- this will show to our user -->
        <div class="stage">
            <!-- content gets added here -->
        </div>

    </div>


<!-- if no user logged in, we prompt for FB login and create account -->
<div id="loginprompt" class="page">
    <a href="#" class="fbReg">Login With FaceBook</a>
</div>
```

I think the problem lays in the getLoginStatus because if I comment that changeToPage function out and move it into the $(document).ready(function() before the event binding, then it works, BUT if I move it after the event binding, then it stops. Why??

I thought if I used the .on binding then it would work once the html arrived on the page through-out my app...

Comment: I think the problem lays in the getLoginStatus because if I comment that changeToPage function out and move it into the $(document).ready(function() before the event binding, then it works, BUT if I move it after the event binding, then it stops. Why??

Answer (score 0):

So assuming I am understanding this correctly. It sounds like this is an event delegation issue. Read more about this here (https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

In this case you should be able to simply switch your listener from:

```
$(".fbReg").on("click", function () {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

To:

```
$("document").on("click", ".fbReg", function () {
    alert("clicked")
})
```

In short, you want to place your event listener on something that you can guarantee exists like body or the document itself.

Comment: this didn't solve the problem. see my modified comment above for another clue.

Comment: Including the click handler inside the document.ready is essentially what Gandhi_rahul suggested. You are binding the event handlers after you have inserted the new html on to the page. You can try moving the click handler into your changeToPage() function to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The better option would be to add the event handler to the `<div class="stage">` which will use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to catch the event for `<a href="#" class="fbReg">` as you are inserting new HTML to the DOM.

or attach the event handlers after the insertion

```
 $(".fbReg").on("click", function()
                {
                    alert("clicked");
                });
```